# How to call a function of the owner object

Tags: javascript

I have several business objects (with different types) that implement functions for a common object, which is assigned to a property of each business object.
It is possible to call the functions declared on business objects from the common object?

Hereafter some similar code:

```js
var Percent= function(){
    this.input= null;
    ...
    this.getValuesRange= function(){
        return [min,max];
    }
    ...
}
var Speed= function(){
    this.input= null;
    ...
    this.getValuesRange= function(){
        return [min,max];
    }
    ...
}
var Input= function(){
    this.inputRange= function(){
        //here I need to call owner's getValuesRange function
    }
}
var input= new Input();
var mySpeed= new Speed();
var rocketSpeed= new Speed();
...
mySpeed.input= input;
rocketSpeed.input= input;
...
facade.enter(mySpeed);
facade.enter(rocketSpeed);
...
```

Comment: You could pass the Speed instance to the Input object and then use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `inputRange` on `Input` to access `getValuesRange`, it has to have access to an instance of `Speed`. Your code has to provide it that instance, there's no built-in "what object references this object via a property" operation in JavaScript. (If there were, it would have to allow for the fact multiple objects can reference the same object, as in your example — both `Speed` instances reference the same `Input` instance.)

Comment: So I understand what you and tomerpacific say is that I should pass the business object instance to Input. Some like Input.currentOwner= mySeed; Isn't it?

Comment: @TJCrowder I cannot fully agree with you because the whole prototype delegation from instances to the Constructor.prototype is built on the fact that multiple objects (the instances) do reference the same object (the Constructor.prototype). 
In that case, the "what object references this object via a property" operation is the 'this' keyword resolution. Because the methods on the Contructor.prototype are able to know which instance they should affect thanks to the 'this' value.

Comment: In fact, my ugly workaround is based on the same concept: each call to the 'inputRange' method will properly set its 'this'.

Comment: Gents, all logic related to input is on Input object, and its current owner instance (of a business object) should be transparent to that logic. That's why mySpeed.getInput().inputRange(); doesn't make sense in this case.  While calling currentOwner.getValuesRange() from the Input instance could work., I wonder if that is the best solution

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with some workarounds. Here an example:

```
var c = 0;

var Speed= function(){
    var mc = c++;

    var _input = null;
    var _inputRange = null;

    this.getInput= function() {
        var self = this;

        _input.inputRange = function() {
            _inputRange.call(self);
        }

        return _input;
    }

    this.setInput= function(input) {
        _input = input;
        _inputRange = input.inputRange;
    }

    this.getValuesRange= function(){
        console.log("Speed", mc);
    }
}

var Input= function(){
    this.inputRange= function(){
        this.getValuesRange()
    }
}

var input= new Input();
var mySpeed= new Speed();
var rocketSpeed= new Speed();

mySpeed.setInput(input);
rocketSpeed.setInput(input);

mySpeed.getInput().inputRange(); // Speed 0
rocketSpeed.getInput().inputRange(); // Speed 1
```

There are many possible pitfalls with this solution. It's here only tho give an idea.